# Play on a Chessboard

Tags: graph-theory, chessboard

Consider an infinite grid $\mathcal G$ of unit square cells. A chessboard polygon is a simple polygon (i.e. not self-intersecting) whose sides lie along the gridlines of $\mathcal G$.

Peter chooses a chessboard polygon($F$) and challenges William to paint some cells of $\mathcal G$ green, such that any chessboard polygon congruent to $F$ has at least $1$ green cell but at most $2020$ green cells. 
Can he choose $F$ to make William's job impossible?

Comment: I don't quite follow. Can't Peter just choose the polygon to be the unit square and Peter can paint every square of $\mathcal{G}$ green?

Comment: He cannot. Also A polygon doesn't have an intersecting edges.

Comment: Can you give an example of a permitted simple polygon then?

Comment: @paulinho I don't understand your comment. Peter chooses the polygon but he doesn't paint anything, William does the painting. If Peter's polygon has just one cell (or any number less than 2020) William wins easily by painting the whole grid green.

Comment: @paulinho Think of it as a game. Peter chooses the shape, William chooses a coloring of the underlying grid, then Peter places the chessboard on the grid. Will wins if there are between $1$ and $2020$ green squares in the chessboard, otherwise Paul wins. The question is, who wins? Paul could choose a unit square, but this is a bad move, because then Will wins by coloring the whole board green. Obviously, Paul needs to choose a chessboard with area at least $2021$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Does "congruent" include the shapes that are the same as the one Peter chooses but rotated?